# Is there a travis ci environment variable to get the current ruby version to be used for the test?

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

in my gemfile, I have:

```
ruby ENV['RUBY_VERSION'] || '2.2.0'
```

RUBY_VERSION is doesn't exist in travis, as I get an error when travis runs saying that it can't run because the environment is set up with one version of ruby, and the gemfile specifies another.

the error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specified ruby-2.2.0
```

Comment: the errors shows that I am. I actually have two rubies specified in the travis.yml: 2.2, and ruby-head.

Comment: cause I want my gemfile to specify 2.2.0, unless travis is doing tests.

Comment: Why do you need to test your app against different versions of Ruby? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: so I know when I can upgrade...................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is - `TRAVIS_RUBY_VERSION`.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Default-Environment-Variables